# Converting a monadic value to an IO in Polysemy

Tags: haskell, monads, free-monad, haskell-polysemy

I am trying to build an automated feature testing suite using `webdriver` and `polysemy` in Haskell. I've gotten as far as defining proper effects and interpreting them into a webdriver WD monad, but now I'm stuck.

I have a value of type `Member BrowserMaster r => Sem r ()` where `BrowserMaster` is my custom capability.

And this is the interpreter:

```
runBrowserMaster :: Members [Embed WD.WD, Embed IO] r => Sem (BrowserMaster ': r) a -> Sem r a
runBrowserMaster = interpret $ \case
  ClickElement bmSelector ->
    let action = (WD.findElem (bmSelectoToSelector bmSelector) >>= WD.click :: WD.WD ())
     in embed action
    {- ... -}
```

Now I'm wondering how to convert the `Embed WD.WD` effect into `Embed IO`, so that I end up with just one.

I tried to craft an interpreter:

```
runWebDriver :: Member (Embed IO) r => Sem (Embed WD.WD ': r) a -> Sem r a
runWebDriver = interpret $
  \a -> embed $ runSession chromeConfig . finallyClose $ do
      setImplicitWait 60000
      setWindowSize (1024, 768)
      unEmbed a
```

(Here `runSession chromeConfig . finallyClose` is a `WD a -> IO a`)

It does work, but it seems to fire up a new browser session for each of the commands instead of starting it just once, doing everything within and closing.

I have an intuition that it has to do something with resource acquisition and release, but I just cannot get my head around this to be able to put it all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that each interpreter will be executed each time an action of the `BrowserMaster` effect is executed. So every time it runs the `runWebDriver` interpreter, which explains why it creates, runs and close the session.

I think what you want to do is instead to create/delete the session once, and execute your whole code in this session. 
Also, since `WD` is already a wrapper around `IO`, I think it's unnecessary to embed both effects.

I am not familiar with your code nor the `webdriver` library, but I assume this would be something along the lines of:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = runSession chromeConfig . finallyClose $ do
  setImplicitWait 60000
  setWindowSize (1024, 768)
  runM . runBrowserMaster $ myBusinessCode

runBrowserMaster :: Member (Embed WD.WD) r => Sem (BrowserMaster ': r) a -> Sem r a
runBrowserMaster = interpret $ \case
  ClickElement bmSelector ->
    let action = (WD.findElem (bmSelectoToSelector bmSelector) >>= WD.click :: WD.WD ())
     in embed action
    {- ... -}
```

Note: If you need to run some `IO` code in the interpreter, use `liftIO` to make it an `WD` action instead, e.g. `liftIO $ putStrLn "Hello world"`.

PS: I recommend renaming the `runBrowserMaster` interpreter to something like `browserMasterToWD` as it better represents what it does: interpret the `BrowserMaster` effect in terms of an `WD` action.

Comment: Wow, thanks! That was the missing piece: I had to initialize the WebDriver outside of the polysemy scope. I decided I didn't want the WD monad to bleed through the system, so I took this one step further. WD monad is just a StateT IO stack, so I wrote an interpreter from WD into State and IO. Your advice + this change resulted in a pretty decent architecture. Again, thanks so much for taking your time to answer my question, I know how much energy it can take!